# TFS configuration for many web application and one library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have a project with MVC Application, Console Tool and library with business logic(BL Library).
Console Tool do data exchange with 3rd party information system.

Both application(MVC and Console Tool) depend  from BL Library.

In future I need build many MVC Apps using BL Library and Console Tool.

How to organize source code in version control system. I use TFS for version control and builds. What branch i need to use?? How to work with them?? How update all web application If use one branch for BL Library and Console Tool and 1 branch per web application??

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setup like the one presented below could be suited for developing multiple `WebSite` - projects that share dependency to your Lib & ConsoleApp:

```
BLLib
    Development
        DEV <-- branch 
            Sources
                BLLib
    MAIN <-- branch
        Sources
            BLLib

ConsoleTool
    Development
        DEV <-- branch 
            Sources
                ConsoleTool
    MAIN <-- branch
        Sources
            ConsoleTool

WebSite
    Development
        DEV <-- branch 
            SharedSources
                BLLib_branch
                ConsoleTool_branch 
            Sources
                WebSite
    MAIN <-- branch
        SharedSources
            BLLib <-- merged folder from $/../BLLib/MAIN/Sources/BLLib
            ConsoleTool <-- merged folder from $/../ConsoleTool
        Sources
            WebSite
```

Each \DEV-branch is the ground where changes happen & \MAIN is a stable line, that is also useful in project-wide merges.
That's a pretty basic setup, in general, it's worth exploring [this](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) fantastic guide in order to check what better fits your needs.